# Setting multilanguage Page title from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, page-title

I had asked a couple of question about multilanguage in asp.net and I am very grateful because the answers have been of much help.

I now face another problem.

I have the page directive:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Galeria.aspx.cs" Inherits="TerapiaFisica.Galeria" %>
```

What I want is to make the Title multilanguage.
I know i can do that from code behind with something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = (string)GetLocalResourceObject("PageTitle");
    }
```

But that's exactly what i don't want to do. I want to make that title multilanguage from the tag in the page directive of the aspx.

Anyone can tell me what to do?
I tried this two options but none of them works:

```
<%@ Page Title=" <%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "PageTitle") %>"
```

and

```
<%@ Page Title="<asp:Localize Text="<%$ Resources: Global, PageTitle %>"
```

Comment: any specific reason why you don't want to do it through code behind?

Comment: i don't want to fill with code the page_load event, and i have to explain that to a couple of friends and i prefer to do that from the aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
<head>
    <title><%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "PageTitle") %></title>
</head>
```

Comment: hey now, that's what I posted in my answer. not sure why I didn't get the cred ;)

Comment: haha rockinthesixstring i didn't gave you the cred because egrunin posted his answer about a minute before you that's all, thank you very much for your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my IDE in front of me, but the one you wrote (below) looks **wrong**

```
<%@ Page Title=" <%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "PageTitle") %>"
```

Did you try

```
<title>
    <%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "PageTitle") %>
<title>
```

Comment: in fact VisualStudio threw an error in both of my cases, and yes your third option is the one that works! without the ';' you wrote before the '%>'. Thank you very much.

Comment: glad it works... don't forget to hit the checkmark.  ps.. the "first" option was your example that I said was wrong.